# PL/SQL CONSTANT variableś compilation consideration

Tags: compiler-construction, plsql, oracle11g

In refer to [Oracle 11g PL/SQL Positions of CONTANT variables in PACKAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517632)
How PL/SQL compiler handles this approach:

```sql
  FUNCTION PARSER(IN_VALUE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    LC_PARAM CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := 'USERNAME';
    LC_MSG   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(80) := REPLACE('Hello USERNAME! How are you today?', LC_PARAM, IN_VALUE);
  BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(LC_MSG, LC_PARAM, LC_PARAM);
  END PARSER;
```

or even this:

```sql
  FUNCTION PARSER(IN_PARAM IN VARCHAR2,
                  IN_VALUE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    LC_MSG CONSTANT VARCHAR2(80) := REPLACE('Hello USERNAME! How are you today?', IN_PARAM, IN_VALUE);
  BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(LC_MSG, IN_PARAM, IN_PARAM);
  END PARSER;
```

Comment: Is the question "will these two pieces of code have similar performance characteristics"?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: More about How compiler handle this. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517632 You wrote that CONSTANTS variables are compiled inline.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand the question.  You're not asking about the performance characteristics of these two approaches?  Are you asking about the intermediate language code that gets generated by the compiler?  Are you asking about the particular optimization of inlining code?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm still learning of it. I'm asking how PL/SQL compiler handles this kind of constants in strictly low-level way. Maybe in my second example in this question variable `LC_MSG` is compiled as standard local variable and only grammar validations prevents assigns any strings to this variable ?

Comment: Your posted code samples are pointless: they use the same string as both target and replacement variables.  So my advice would be to chuck the functions.  Perhaps if you could come up with a *proper example* we would have a better chance of understanding the point you're trying to understand.